# How can I authorize a user to make it so only the user in Rails can see it's own content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-7

I am working with a rails 7 application and using devise for authentication.
I have a bookings controller which looks like this

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_booking, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index 
        @bookings = Booking.all 
    end

    def show 

    end 

    def new 
        @booking = Booking.new 
    end

    def create
        @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
        respond_to do |format| 
            if @booking.save
                format.html {redirect_to booking_url(@booking), notice: "Booking was successfully created"}
            else 
                format.html {render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity}
            end
        end
    end

    def edit 

    end 

    def update
        respond_to do |format| 
            if @booking.update(booking_params)
                format.html {redirect_to booking_url(@booking), notice: "Booking was successfully updated"}
            else 
                format.html {render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity}
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy 
        @booking.destroy 
        respond_to do |format| 
            format.html {redirect_to bookings_url, notice: "Booking was successfully destroyed"} 
        end
    end
    

    private 
    def booking_params 
        params.require(:booking).permit(:room_id, :start, :end, :purpose, :user_id)
    end
        
    def set_booking 
        @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

User model which looks like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :bookings
end
```

When I am logged in, I am able to view and edit any user's content, however I want to restrict it so only user_id 1 can see booking belonging to user_id 2. Right now any user can edit any booking regardless of who the booking belongs to.
Thank you!

Comment: you can check you CanCanCan gem. It provides an ability file where you can dictate which models a user is able to use. Also provides scoping through `accessible_by`

Comment: I would really recommend Pundit over CanCanCan. Pundit is a little harder to wrap your head around initially but CanCanCan just doesn't deal with any kind of complexity beyond a Blorgh application gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is alter the below private method :

```
def set_booking 
   @booking = current_user.bookings.find(params[:id])
end
```

and also your index method :

```
def index 
  @bookings = current_user.bookings 
end
```

And new and create too...
and move your authentication callback on top of callbacks.

Also as advised in the comments you can use gem Pundit in order to authorize properly in case you get more complex scenarios.